# how to pass file object using structure?

Tags: c++

I am facing one issue while passing file object using structure and the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct abc
{
    ofstream &t;

}stabc;

class dc
{
    public:
    static void fun(stabc *ad);
    static stabc ab;

};
int main()
{
    ofstream str;
    str.open("hello.csv",ios::app);
    str<<"hellllooo"<<endl;
    dc d;
    d.ab.t=str;
    dc::fun(&d.ab);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
void dc::fun(stabc *ad)
{
    ofstream& st=ad->t;
    st<<"kikiki"<<endl;

}
```

It gives uninitialized reference member abc::t. Please tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the reference `t` in the **[member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361)**.
References are special construct which need to be initialized at the time of creation. Since you do not initialize the member reference the compiler emits the diagnostic.

Member references **must** to be initialized in the member initializer list.

**[Online Sample](http://ideone.com/38qGfE)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct stabc
{
    ofstream &t;
    stabc(ofstream &obj):t(obj){}
};

int main()
{
    ofstream obj2;
    stabc obj(obj2);
    return 0;
}
```

Also note in C++(*unlike C*) you do not need to `typedef` a structure in order to use it without the keyword `struct`. You can simply use the structure name without pre-pending the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-seat references. They have to be initialized and there is no "default" value for a reference. So you would need to construct an instance of an `abc` using the reference to the file stream object:

```
struct abc
{
    std::ofstream &t;
};
```

then

```
abc myabc = {str};
```

or give `abc` a constructor and use the constructor initialization list:

```
struct abc
{
  abc(std::ofstream& o) : t(o) {}
  std::ofstream &t;
};

abc myabc(str);
```